# How to get the UIComponent who is calling the managed bean's getter method?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is it possible to know what `UIComponent` is calling the getter of some property in managed bean?

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SomeBean {

    private String color;

    public String getColor() {
        // Here I would like to know which UIComponent called this method.
        return color;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`UIComponent#getCurrentComponent()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getCurrentComponent%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) for this.

```
public String getColor() {
    UIComponent component = UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    // ...

    return color;
}
```